# Json to html table. Cannot parse to table heading because json object's field name starts with capital?

Tags: html, json, html-table, dynatable

I am trying to use [Dynatable](https://dynatable.com/#existing-json) library to convert json objects to html table.

PS: This problem also persists for other library such as [DataTable](https://datatables.net)

However, currently my entire table's cell value is undefined.

Here is my sample Json data

```
[
   {"Adult":2,"Child":1}, 
   {"Adult":3,"Child":2},
   {"Adult":4,"Child":1}
]
```

And here is my HTML table

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>               
            <th>Adult</th>
            <th>Child</th>             
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is the javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:51071/api/Foo',               
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $("#myTable").dynatable({                    
                dataset: {
                    records: response
                }
            });
        },              
        dataType: 'json'
    });
});
```

Any particular reason why I am getting undefined value?

In their documentation for [converting attribute names](https://dynatable.com/#converting-attribute-names) they mention default naming convention to be `camelcase` and example given was `favoriteMusic`.
Are they expecting my field name to start with small letter?

**Update 1:**

Turns out it is because the field names start with capital letter.
I changed my json data to following and it worked

```
[
   {"adult":2,"child":1}, 
   {"adult":3,"child":2},
   {"adult":4,"child":1}
]
```

Any idea for a work around to make it work with field name starting with capital letter?

Answer (score -1):

This is what I ended up doing

```
    function firstLetterLowerCase(str) {
        return str.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + str.substr(1);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:51071/api/Foo',               
            success: function (response) {

                response = response.map(function(resObj) {
                    var obj = {};
                    for (key in resObj) {
                        if (resObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            obj[firstLetterLowerCase(key)] = resObj[key];
                        }
                    }
                    return obj;
                });
                $("#myTable").dynatable({                    
                    dataset: {
                        records:response
                    }
                });                },              
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    });
```

So basically wrote a function to convert first letter of json object's field name from capital to small.

This might not be as performant when number of entries are huge.

Comment: please do provide reason for voting down the answer if you do downvote. Also, if you think this answer is not good, do provide a better solution. It could help someone else in future